# shorten code for jquery function with data()

Tags: jquery

I've written some jQuery code for my site. Unfortunately, the code that I use is longer than it needs to be and can be shortened. I have tried many different ways to get shorten my code but problem is that my knowledge of jQuery is very weak.

This question is not for easy way to get expected result but to acquire more knowledge.

So, first my HTML code.

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area class="18482" data-maphilight={"fillColor":"B97F5D"} shape="rect" coords=540,4,598,129" href="#"/> 
    <area class="18521" data-maphilight={"fillColor":"AAAAAA"} shape="rect" coords=486,4,540,130" href="#"/> 
    <area class="18552" shape="rect" coords=433,4,487,130" href="#"/> 
</map>
```

We got here three different shapes with their own backgrounds which are defined by `data-maphilight` attribute. Now with code below i set some functions for each shape with different background. Also one function supports shape which don't have a `data-maphilight` attribute, and in this case he modify different values.

```
$(function() {
  $("area[data-maphilight*='B97F5D']").mouseover(function(e) { 
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = 'B97F5D';
    data.fillOpacity = '0.7';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = 'B97F5D';
    data.fillOpacity = '1';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });
  $("area[data-maphilight*='AAAAAA']").mouseover(function(e) { 
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = 'AAAAAA';
    data.fillOpacity = '0.7';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = 'AAAAAA';
    data.fillOpacity = '1';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });
  $("area:not([data-maphilight])").mouseover(function(e) { 
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = '444444';
    data.fillOpacity = '1';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    data.fillColor = '000000';
    data.fillOpacity = '1';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });
});
```

As you see, this code is very unprofessional. Can somebody help me with example of more professional code, and by that I mean much shorter, so that I get the same result? I spent two hours trying various combinations and I could not get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten it by bundling all the repetition code into a function:

```
function maphilightTrigger($area, alwaysOn, fillColor, fillOpacity) {
  var data = {};
  data.alwaysOn = alwaysOn;
  data.fillColor = fillColor;
  data.fillOpacity = fillOpacity;
  $area.data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
}
```

Then call the function, passing in all the variable data as parameters:

```
$("area[data-maphilight*='B97F5D']").mouseover(function(e) { 
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, 'B97F5D', '0.7')
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, 'B97F5D', '1')
});

$("area[data-maphilight*='AAAAAA']").mouseover(function(e) { 
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, 'AAAAAA', '0.7')
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, 'AAAAAA', '1')
});

$("area:not([data-maphilight])").mouseover(function(e) { 
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, '444444', '1')
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  maphilightTrigger( $(this), true, '000000', '1')
});
```

You could further shorten it by bundling in the selector and event:

```
function maphilightTrigger($area, event, alwaysOn, fillColor, fillOpacity) {
  var data = {};
  data.alwaysOn = alwaysOn;
  data.fillColor = fillColor;
  data.fillOpacity = fillOpacity;

  $area.on( event, function(e) {
    $area.data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });
}
```

And calling the function like this:

```
maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='B97F5D']"), mouseover, true, 'B97F5D', '0.7' )
maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='B97F5D']"), mouseout, true, 'B97F5D', '1' )

maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='AAAAAA']"), mouseover, true, 'AAAAAA', '0.7' )
maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='AAAAAA']"), mouseout, true, 'AAAAAA', '1' )

maphilightTrigger( $("area:not([data-maphilight]"), mouseover, true, '444444', '1' )
maphilightTrigger( $("area:not([data-maphilight]"), mouseout, true, '000000', '1' )
```

You could shorten it even further by assuming an area will always require mouseover and mouseout events:

```
function maphilightTrigger($area, alwaysOnMouseOver, fillColorMouseOver, fillOpacityMouseOver, alwaysOnMouseOut, fillColorMouseOut, fillOpacityMouseOut) {
  var dataMouseOver = {};
  dataMouseOver.alwaysOn = alwaysOnMouseOver;
  dataMouseOver.fillColor = fillColorMouseOver;
  dataMouseOver.fillOpacity = fillOpacityMouseOver;

  var dataMouseOver = {};
  dataMouseOver.alwaysOn = alwaysOnMouseOut;
  dataMouseOver.fillColor = fillColorMouseOut;
  dataMouseOver.fillOpacity = fillOpacityMouseOut;

  $area.mouseover(function(e) {
    $area.data('maphilight', dataMouseOver).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $area.data('maphilight', dataMouseOver).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });
}
```

And calling the function like this:

```
maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='B97F5D']"), true, 'B97F5D', '0.7', true, 'B97F5D', '1' )
maphilightTrigger( $("area[data-maphilight*='AAAAAA']"), true, 'AAAAAA', '0.7', true, 'AAAAAA', '1' )
maphilightTrigger( $("area:not([data-maphilight]"), true, '444444', '1', true, '000000', '1' )
```

Though I think that last one is pushing it a bit too far.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code :

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area class="18482" data-maphilight={"fillColor":"B97F5D"} shape="rect" coords=540,4,598,129" href="#"/> 
    <area class="18521" data-maphilight={"fillColor":"AAAAAA"} shape="rect" coords=486,4,540,130" href="#"/> 
    <area class="18552" data-maphilight shape="rect" coords=433,4,487,130" href="#"/> 
</map>
```

and the script is now

```
$(function() {
  $("area[data-maphilight]").mouseover(function(e) { 
    var fillColor = $(this).data("maphilight").fillColor;
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;   
    data.fillColor = fillColor!=undefined ?fillColor:'444444'
    data.fillOpacity = '0.7';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    var fillColor = $(this).data("maphilight").fillColor;
    var data = {};
    data.alwaysOn = true; 
    data.fillColor = fillColor!=undefined ?fillColor:'000000'   
    data.fillOpacity = '1';
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  });  
});
```

Just check quickly, did not run it but it's the shortest as far i know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the mouseout and mouseover events for `$("area['']")` and `$("area:not['']")`, I just called in `$("area")` and added a check inside for the data you are looking for. I created the var `maphilightData` and checked if its defined in the currently selected object.

```
$(function () {
    $("area").mouseover(function (e) {
        var maphilightData = $(this).data("maphilight");
        var data = {};
        data.alwaysOn = true;
        data.fillColor = (maphilightData != undefined? maphilightData.fillColor : "444444");
        data.fillOpacity = (maphilightData != undefined ? "0.7" : "1");
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        var maphilightData = $(this).data("maphilight");
        var data = {};
        data.alwaysOn = true;
        data.fillColor = (maphilightData != undefined ? maphilightData.fillColor : "000000");
        data.fillOpacity = "1";
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
});
```

Or you can also concatenate it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("area").mouseover(function (e) {
    debugger;
        var maphilightData = $(this).data("maphilight");
        var data = { alwaysOn: true, fillColor: (maphilightData != undefined ? maphilightData.fillColor : "444444"), fillOpacity : (maphilightData != undefined ? "0.7" : "1") };
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        var maphilightData = $(this).data("maphilight");
        var data = { alwaysOn: true, fillColor: (maphilightData != undefined ? maphilightData.fillColor : "000000"), fillOpacity : "1" };
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
});
```